# create a dictionary from string that each character is key and value

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the best way for me to create a dictionary from a string that key is each character and its upper case and value is its opposite case? I can use two line dictionary comprehensive but any better way?
ex:

> string: abc => {'a': 'A', 'b': 'B', 'c': 'C', 'C': 'c', 'B': 'b', 'A': 'a'}

```
string = 'abc'
d = { i:i.upper() for i in string}
d.update({ i.upper():i for i in string})
```

Comment: Is it just these specific characters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [swapcase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.swapcase):

```
s = 'abc'

result = dict(zip(s + s.swapcase(), s.swapcase() + s))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'C': 'c', 'b': 'B', 'B': 'b', 'a': 'A', 'A': 'a', 'c': 'C'}
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC: You can do this as follows,

```
string_dict = {
    char: char.upper() if char == char.lower() else char.lower()
    for char in (string.lower() + string.upper())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do the same

```
import string
d=dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase[:3],string.ascii_uppercase[:3]))
d.update(dict(zip(string.ascii_uppercase[:3],string.ascii_lowercase[:3])))
```